# How do I import a text file with no separators in python, using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, import

How do I import a file with no separators?

I have a file named `text.txt`  which contains 2 lines of text:

> 00000000011100000000000000000000
>   00000000011111110000000000000000

When I use

> f = open("text.txt")
>   data = np.loadtxt(f)

I get

> [  1.11000000e+22   1.11111100e+22]

Using `sep=""` changes nothing.

I would like to get this result, in the form of many single digit integers:

> [ [00000000011100000000000000000000]
>   [00000000011111110000000000000000] ]

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**  Thank you all for the great answers and the many valid solutions to an awkward question.

Comment: Exactly what result do you *want*?

Comment: Are you complaining because NumPy is printing your numbers in exponential notation, or because it's giving you an array of shape (2,) instead of (2, 1)?

Comment: Are these supposed to be two strings or many single digit integers?

Comment: I am complaining because NumPy is printing my numbers in exponential notation, AND because it's giving me an array of shape (2,) instead of (2, 1)!  :)

Comment: You seem to contradict yourself, should there be many columns or only one? Many single digit integers would mean many columns.

Comment: Do you just want each line in a list? Note that `[[00000000011100000000000000000000]]` is actually a _string_ `[['00000000011100000000000000000000']]`, otherwise you would get the numerical representation, the `1.11000000e+22`. The way something is _printed_ is inconsequential. The more important thing is how its stored.

Comment: Is this supposed to be in binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't give numpy any guidance, it has to guess the types you want.

If your data look like decimal-format integers, it will try to interpret them that way and fit them into an int32. But `00000000011100000000000000000000` (which is obviously equal to `11100000000000000000000`) takes 74 bits, so that won't work. So, it falls back to storing them in a `float64`.

If you didn't realize that 1.11E22 means the same thing as 11100000000000000000000, you need to read up on [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). 1.11E22 is Python (and C, and many other programming languages) shortcut for 1.11 * 10**22. Anyway, the reason you're getting scientific notation is that the default printout for an array of `float64` is `%g`-style, meaning something like "simple notation if `-4 <= exponent < precision`, otherwise exponential".

So, that's why you get `[1.11000000e+22 1.11111100e+22]`.

---

The reason you get an array of shape `(2,)` instead of `(1, 2)` is that by default, `loadtxt` squeezes mono-dimensional axes. Add `ndmin=2` if that's what you want.

---

If you ask NumPy to treat the data as strings, it will guess the right length, and read them as strings:

```
>>> np.loadtxt(f, dtype=str, ndmin=2)
array([['00000000011100000000000000000000'],
       ['00000000011111110000000000000000']],
      dtype='|S32')
```

Or, if you ask it to treat the data as Python objects, it'll leave them as Python `str` objects:

```
>>> np.loadtxt(f, dtype=object, ndmin=2)
array([['00000000011100000000000000000000'],
       ['00000000011111110000000000000000']],
      dtype=object)
```

If you want them to be 128-bit integers… well, you probably don't have `int128` support in your build, so you can't have that.

If you were hoping for them to be interpreted as bit strings and stored in 32-bit ints, you have to do that in two steps. I don't think NumPy can vectorize parsing bit strings usefully, so you might as well do that part in Python:

```
>>> np.fromiter((int(line, 2) for line in f), dtype=int)
array([7340032, 8323072])
```

If you want them interpreter as single-digit integers, there's no way to do that directly, but you can do that in two steps as well (e.g., read it as an array of 2 strings, treat each string as a sequence of characters, broadcast `np.vectorize(int)` over it).

Almost anything you want to do is doable, but you have to actually know what you want to do and be able to explain it to a human before you'll be able to explain it to numpy.

Answer (score 8):

I'll take the statement "I would like to get this result, in the form of many single digit integers:" literally, and ignore the format of the sample that follows it (which appears to be just two integers, rather than many single digit integers).  You can do that with [`genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) by using the arguments `delimiter=1` and `dtype=int`.  When `delimiter` is an integer or a sequence of integers, the values are interpreted as the field widths of a file containing fixed-width fields of data.

For example:

```
In [15]: genfromtxt('text.txt', delimiter=1, dtype=int)
Out[15]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Best answer here, by far.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you correctly, try the following:

```
a = np.loadtxt('text.txt', dtype=np.character)
a = np.array(map(lambda x: map(int, x), a))
```

Output:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

This solution is a bit dumb and it defeats the use of `np.loadtxt` though, but sometimes we just want things to work.